# Sound stop working suddenly...? Only work again with a new user

Tags: sound, 13.10, login

My sound stop working all of a sudden on my computer! When it started, I had to reboot and everything was getting back to normal but then it stopped coming back.

I try al sort of things! (Alsamixer, killall, restarting services!

The strange thing is that the sound work on the login screen. I created a new user avec the sound work on that session.

Any hint on what happenend?

I have an Asus F8P with Ubuntu 13.10

Thank you :-)

Daniel

Comment: sometimes the sound will mute when booting(not sure why) look at the speaker icon in the top panel, if the is an "X" by it it is muted, middle clicking will unmute.  if this is not the case, you will need to post your audio card....in a terminal type `lspci`  about the third item down should be your "audio device"

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Actually, both of your answer work! I had to change a mute in alsamixer! But with PavuControl, I was to change the setting to make my sound work again :-D!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `pavucontrol` - PulseAudio Volume Control

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

This had more advanced configuration options, so may work.

Another thing to try is moving the configuration. If the problem seems to occur only on your user, and works elsewhere, try this to move the relevant config files  *(some maybe be relevant, some may be not, but this will just back them up anyway)*:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.bak
mv ~/.gstreamer-0.10 ~/.gstreamer-0.10.bak
mv ~/.local/share/gstreamer-1.0 ~/.local/share/gstreamer-1.0.bak
```

If you want to restore them

```
mv ~/.config/pulse.bak ~/.config/pulse
mv ~/.gstreamer-0.10.bak ~/.gstreamer-0.10
mv ~/.local/share/gstreamer-1.0.bak ~/.local/share/gstreamer-1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

On my old install of Ubuntu, the GUI mixer sometimes show that the volume is maxed, but I don't get sound. Back then, this is how I got around my issue.

In terminal, type:

```
alsamixer
```

Look underneath each bar, if you see **MM**, then use the left and right arrow keys to navigate to it and press **M** to unmute. The up and down arrow keys to change volume for each output or input.

Your problem might be more complex, in which case you can try the suggestion by wilf regarding moving around the configuration files.

If that doesn't do it, you can always try this.

```
sudo apt-get --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
```

Good luck!

Comment: Good answer, but note the OP did already mention `alsamixer` ;-) - even though [that did eventually help.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/407347/sound-stop-working-suddenly-only-work-again-with-a-new-user/407363#comment523874_407347)